# Where can I find a complete list of the standard subgraphs offered by tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

One can use `subgraph I_nm` and `subgraph C_n`, is there a complete list? In particular I'm looking for a linear subgraph, but a complete list would be extremely helpful.

---

I just found this in the documentation:

> The library graphs.standard defines a number of such graphs, including the complete clique Kn on n nodes, the complete bipartite graph Kn,m with shores sized n and m, the cycle Cn on n nodes, the path Pn on n nodes, and the independent set In on n nodes.

Which does not appear to be a complete list, but maybe it is!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for [§19.10.1 Graph Macros](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=300) in the manual? Here’s a list:

- **`I_n`**     
  independent set
- **`I_nm`**    
  two-shore independent set
- **`K_n`**     
  complete clique
- **`K_nm`**    
  complete bipartite graph
- **`C_n`**     
  cycle
- **`P_n`**     
  path
- **`Grid_n`**  
  grid

If you look at the [source code](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibrarygraphs.standard.code.tex?content-type=text%2Fplain), however, you’ll notice this undocumented macro:

- **`G_np`**    
  random (undirected) graph according to the [*G*<sub>*n*,*p*</sub> model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29) (for each pair of vertices, there is an edge between them with probability *p*)

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[
    nodes={circle}, edges={gray!60, semithick}, clockwise, radius=8em,
    n=9, p=0.3
] {
    subgraph I_n; subgraph G_np
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it, and it is also useful to hear they are called graph macros, thank you!