# Drawing multiple circles on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, polarplot

I want to draw a unit circle with multiple circles with centred on `(cos(x),sin(x))`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);

\coordinate (a) at (2;10);

\draw (a) circle (0.3cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I define points using polar coordinates to draw a circle at `(2cos(10),2sin(10))`?

Comment: you can use the polar syntax `(10:2)` which is `(<angle>:radius)`

Comment: Welcome to Tex SE.  Have you tried searching for similar drawings?  The are many like this on this site.

Answer (score 10):

Without polar coordinates, this can easily be done as follows

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}

\def \f {1.0}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \a in {0, 30, ..., 350 }
        \draw ({\f*cos(\a)}, {\f*sin(\a)}) circle (0.2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: @daruma If this answers your question, the local way to say 'thanks!' is to accept the answer by clicking on the greyed-out tick at the top-left corner of the answer. (When you have more reputation, you'll also be able to vote answers up, but I don't think you can do that quite yet.)

Answer (score 7):

*With* polar coordinates this can also be done :)

```
 \draw (\a:1) circle (0.2cm);
```

The syntax is `(<angle>:<radius>)`. The output is

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \a in {0, 30, ..., 350 }
 \draw (\a:1) circle (0.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or, alternatively, using the `graphs` library, allows you to use

```
\graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum width=.2cm},
  clockwise,
  radius=1cm,
  empty nodes,
  n=12]{subgraph I_n};
```

here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum width=.2cm},clockwise,radius=1cm,empty nodes,n=12]{subgraph I_n};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For reference, see [Where can I find a complete list of the standard subgraphs offered by tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208147/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-the-standard-subgraphs-offered-by-tikz)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\N{10}
\def\offsetAngle{19}
\def\radius{5mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\N]{0}{360}{2 t \offsetAngle\space add PtoC}{X}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\the\numexpr\Xnodecount-1\relax}{\pscircle(X\i){\radius}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The counter intuitive name in `\Xnodecount` is actually the last index of the zero-based node array `X`. If the curve is a closed curve, we have to subtract 1 from `\Xnodecount` to remove `X9` (based on the above example) that is actually equal to `X0`.

[image]